# How do match static html files in webapp2 using a regex?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

So I want to serve html files basically as they are from the root directory as well as some subdirectories, so in my app.yaml file I put:

```
- url: /(.*\.(html))$
  static_dir: /\1
  upload:/(.*\.(html))$
```

but this won't match my index.html sitting in the root directory. How do I match this? And I assume if I have subdirectories I could add them as well like:

```
- url: /sub_dir/(.*\.(html))$
  static_dir: sub_dir/\1
  upload: sub_dir/(.*\.(html))$
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confusing `static_dir` with `static_files`.  Try:

```
- url: /(.*\.(html))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(html))$
```

That points to the `.html` file at your root.

Comment: Seems a little closer now I see:

    /index.html not found

as the error message, but I am looking right at index.html and it's in the root, any ideas?

I tried this:

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: / and it worked.

Comment: Close! I also had to delete the trailing slash from the static_files entry so it looks like "\1". Thanks a lot!